# get json string within the xml

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

I am really struck with xml parsing .I have an xmlstring  like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://a.com  /">{"Id":87,"Name":"jo@a.com","FirstName":"Jo","LastName":"var","Profile":"","Designation":""}</string>
```

I want to get the json as string  .. I dont know how to do this..

my try given below.. am really struck pls help me

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                                    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(fromServer));

                                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");
```

Comment: Better ask for pure json

Comment: Are you there, do you really need answer..

Comment: yes... still searching for answer :(

Comment: Check my answer, might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

I was posting this answer just to help, but this is not the best approach.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://a.com  /">

</string>
```

These will come along with your response, so they are same every time. just replace them with empty space like this

```
String str=yourjsonresponse;

str=str.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"," ");
str=str.replace("<string xmlns=\"http://a.com  /\">"," ");
str=str.replace("</string>"," ");
```

Seems strange, but will work.

And the alternative will be using `jsoup`, Decice what you wanna go for.

**But the Best will be getting the pure json respose**